# Reading SQL Server trading data table in a 2D or 3D Array or List

Tags: c#

I am building a simple backtest program with C# and MS SQL, and now I have a SQL table with these columns: open, high, low, close, volume, date.
I think I should push the whole table into a 2D array first then much easier to do analysis with it. How do I do this? Thanks.

Comment: Hi, You need to be more specific about the 2D array that you have in mind.

Comment: You mean which data structure? I guess it would be linked list.

Comment: It really depends on what and how you're planning to analise. e.g. it could make sense to represent it as anything from tuples to ADO.Net DataTables.